# Where can I download Ext-JS 3.2.1 non commercial source?

Tags: extjs

Tried going through Sencha's version archive located here: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_Version_Archives but it just linked me to a blank page.  Does anyone know where else I could find it?

Comment: For those of you who may of come here for the same reason as OP (like me). I just successfully downloaded 3.2.1 from the sencha site link listed above. It appears they fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, looks like Sencha team is yet to fix that issue. For the time, you can access the ExtJs 3.2.1 from the below link:

http://i.download.idg.pl/fannef/7ac06b30d95d34e3b5e4d252a1d90db3/4d7da6f8//vol2/w95/Biblioteki/EXTJS/ext-3.2.1.zip